# Problems compiling with OkHttp version 4.0.0-RC1

Tags: okhttp

When I compile my code with Ant using OkHttp version 4.0.0-RC1 I see warnings and errors:

```
[javac] warning: unknown enum constant DeprecationLevel.WARNING
[javac] warning: unknown enum constant DeprecationLevel.ERROR
[javac] warning: unknown enum constant DeprecationLevel.ERROR
[javac] /Users/janne/work/github/pureload/pureit/packages/purehttp/src/com/pureload/net/http/impl/okhttp/HeaderUtil.java:51: error: cannot access KMappedMarker
[javac]       Set<String> headerNames = headers.names();
[javac]                                        ^
[javac]   class file for kotlin.jvm.internal.markers.KMappedMarker not found
[javac] warning: unknown enum constant DeprecationLevel.ERROR
...
```

I simply replaced the OkHttp jar files from version 3.12.1 with the latest 4.0.0-RC1. I'm using Java 11.

I assume this is Kotlin related (?), but I do not know how to solve this...

Comment: Ask on the QtHttp forum or source forge

Comment: Did you add the Kotlin standard library to your project’ s dependencies? You must do that.

Comment: No I did not. But I have done so now and it compiles as expected.
Thanks!
(I believe this would be useful information to add to the "Upgrading to OkHttp 4" document as well)